# Should i store my facebook_ids as Integer or as String in mongo?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I have the following (using mongoid):

```
class FacebookUser
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps    
  field :uid,   type: String
  field :friends,   type: Array
end
```

I am using mongoid and am wondering whether to store facebook_ids and facebook_ids_of_friends(Array) as BigDecimal, Integer or String.  I will be using the uid for queries so am somewhat concerned about speed.

OR:

```
class FacebookUser
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps    
  field :uid,   type: Integer
  field :friends,   type: Array  #???How do I get this to store ints instead of strings
end
```

To avoid casting things repeatedly, I believe that the first option is better but wanted to get another opinion? In addition, how would I store an Array with  Integer if I go with option 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
class FacebookUser

    identity :type => String

end
```

due to line `identity :type => String` your id of model will become String type and you can save facebook user id(uid) directly in there instead of creating a new field. The queries like finding users will be really easy and fast

For e.g.

find one user

```
FacebookUser.find(facebook user id)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a string. The only reason to use numeric types is if you will be doing calculations on the data. It is nonsensical to try to add two user id's so they should not be stored as integers.

Comment: Calculation isn't the only reason to choose integers agains string. Indexing integers is more efficient than strings, since mongodb is using B-tree indexes, like other RDBMS databases.